# Why my bcrypt.compare() function returns false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, bcrypt, strapi

I'm trying to implement a password validation system to accept a user's "update password" request.
I'm using Strapi as my backend and Next.js as my frontend.
Strapi says it uses "*bcrypt with autogenerated salt and hash*" ([mentioned here](https://forum.strapi.io/t/what-is-the-encryption-used-by-strapi-in-the-password-fields/4149))
so the stored password is encrypted.
I use MongoDB for my database.
The user is registered, I use it for all my tests so I know the password is correct.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong ?
I am very new to this.

Thank you.

**Comparison code in my controller file** :
I did this but it always return false (backend):

```
const comparePass = await bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password);
  if(comparePass){
    ctx.throw(200, 'valid password !')
  }else{
    ctx.throw(400, 'wrong password !')
  }
```

When I debbug I can see in my console that:

oldPassword = 'maddie'

user.password ='$2a$10$tEXnOI.OASIeL0BsG2Go/ecHjXn38xNnM9HVHJlPnBFpqSRe6Yyf6'

which is correct

**Hashing code**- In my backend, **this code below used to hash the password** when the user register:

```
hashPassword(user = {}) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (!user.password || this.isHashed(user.password)) {
    resolve(null);
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(`${user.password}`, 10, (err, hash) => {
      resolve(hash);
    });
  }
});
```

},

**Complete code in my User.js service** including the hashing code:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * User.js service
 *
 * @description: A set of functions similar to controller's actions to avoid code duplication.
 */

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const { sanitizeEntity, getAbsoluteServerUrl } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Promise to count users
   *
   * @return {Promise}
   */

  count(params) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').count(params);
  },

  /**
   * Promise to search count users
   *
   * @return {Promise}
   */

  countSearch(params) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').countSearch(params);
  },

  /**
   * Promise to add a/an user.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  async add(values) {
    if (values.password) {
      values.password = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.hashPassword(
        values
      );
    }

    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').create(values);
  },

  /**
   * Promise to edit a/an user.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  async edit(params, values) {
    if (values.password) {
      values.password = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.hashPassword(
        values
      );
    }

    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').update(params, values);
  },

  /**
   * Promise to fetch a/an user.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  fetch(params, populate) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne(params, populate);
  },

  /**
   * Promise to fetch authenticated user.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  fetchAuthenticatedUser(id) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').findOne({ id }, ['role']);
  },

  /**
   * Promise to fetch all users.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  fetchAll(params, populate) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').find(params, populate);
  },

  hashPassword(user = {}) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if (!user.password || this.isHashed(user.password)) {
        resolve(null);
      } else {
        bcrypt.hash(`${user.password}`, 10, (err, hash) => {
          resolve(hash);
        });
      }
    });
  },

  isHashed(password) {
    if (typeof password !== 'string' || !password) {
      return false;
    }

    return password.split('$').length === 4;
  },

  /**
   * Promise to remove a/an user.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  async remove(params) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').delete(params);
  },

  async removeAll(params) {
    return strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').delete(params);
  },

  validatePassword(password, hash) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, hash);
  },
```

Comment: You are hashing it wrong somehow. I checked the two strings and they do not match.

Comment: Yes, I checked with https://bcrypt-generator.com/ and the password do not match even though it is the right password.
I created a new user and the comparison result returned "true" !

When debugging I found out that a pending promise caused a wrong hashing. Not sure if this was the also the cause of my initial problem.

Comment: This `hashPassword` function that you have written in your user service file, where have you used it in code? I can only see code being called from the `user-permissions` plugin via `await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.hashPassword(values)`. You must be calling `await strapi.services.users.hashPassword(user)` somewhere at least right? or if you were calling it within the service file itself, `await this.hasPassword(user)` somewhere at least right?